# Definition of discrete $\mathcal{l}_1$norm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, vectors

The $\mathcal{l}_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is 
$$ \|{v}\|_1=\sum_{j=1}^n\left|v_j\right|$$
and the definition of  $\|\cdot\|_{1,h}$ is
$$\|{v}\|_{1,h}=h\sum_{j=1}^n\left|v_j\right|$$

My question is:
Is correct define $\|v\|_{1,h}^* =h^2\sum_{j=1}^n\left|v_j\right|$?

Answer (score 1):

The three properties of the norm function are still preserved: norm(v)=0 iff v=0, norm(av)=abs(a)norm(v) and norm(u+v)<=norm(u)+norm(v) if h is real and not 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I saw this http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/discrete-lp-norms-for-non-uniform-grid I'm confused